# Para que serve a função "done" no Passport?

Tags: node.js, passport-js

Tenho começado a aprender a forma de autenticação local com `passport-local`, fornecida pelo Passport, e fiquei com dúvidas com relação a utilidade da função `done` dentro do processo de autenticação. O que ela faz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, na [documentação](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/) do Passport existe um exemplo com `done`, que provavelmente é o que você está citando:

```js
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

O `done` é o **Verify Callback** (vide documentação), ou seja, é um método interno chamado [`verified`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L80) responsável por continuar o processo de autenticação, retornando um erro, falha ou o usuário autenticado. Uma explicação mais detalhada pode ser encontrada na [documentação](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/#verify-callback), mas em resumo temos:

- `return done(err);` correspondendo ao `self.error(err)` do método `verify`. Esse é o caso de quando ocorre uma exception, por exemplo.
- `return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });` correspondendo ao `self.fail(info)` do método `verify`. Esse é o caso de quando ocorre uma falha na autenticação (senha incorreta, usuário incorreto ou outro motivo).
- `return done(null, user);` correspondendo ao `self.success(user, info)` do método `verify`. Esse é o caso de quando as credenciais são válidas e o *callback* passa o usuário autenticado para o Passport :)